# variable in HREF not working correctly

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to create a link in a Drupal views-view-fields.tpl that links to the original content but for some reason it's not working.  The code I have tried:

```
<a href="<?php $fields['path']->content; ?>">Read more</a>
```

and

```
<?php $link = $fields['path']->content;?>
 <a href="<?php $link ?>"> Read more</a>
```

as well as adding single quotes.  The above points the rendered link to the current page/ view.  When I echo $link_path i get /?q=node/1544 , which is correct.

I have also tried to create the URL by using

```
$link = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/node/' . $node->nid;
<a href="<?php $link ?>"> more </a>
```

The above shows the correct link when I echo it but, again in the rendered link it points to the current page/ drupal view.

What am I missing? I have to add that I only have about 3 months Drupal/PHP experience so still lots to learn.

Thanks :)

Comment: And there's another site compromised by a security problem. You really shouldn't be outputting links like that, but use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7), or otherwise rely on Drupals/Views built in functionality to generate links.

Answer (score 2):

The secure alternative would be to use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to generate the link.
In your current code, it's very likely that you've created a security problem.

`l('More', $fields['path']->content)` would be better.

But in answer to your original question. you are missing echo statement here

```
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>"> more </a>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I noticed the missing echo after I posted this.  It doesn't work with my first example, however, as it renders /?q=node/1545"> and that link points to http://192.168.1.200/%3Cspan%20class= but I never tried the 2nd one with the echo and that seemed to have worked.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: Initially I voted down on the solution because it encourages unsafe code. I changed my mind and edited in the safer option at the top instead.

Comment: I tried <?php print l('More', $fields['path']->content); ?> but the link it returns is http://192.168.1.200/?q=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22field-content%22%3E/%3Fq%3Dnode/1546%3C/span%3E  -- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, so for some reason I just can't get it to work if I use fields['path']->content); to generate the link even though the output of just that line seems correct.  I managed to do it by using echo l('More', 'node/'.$nid);  Is this fine or are there also security issues with this?  THanks.